# How can I persuade a wordpress bitnami module to operate on a subdomain?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, subdomain, wordpress, bitnami

So I have bitnami's LAMP stack running, and I have a wordpress module installed within it.

I want my wordpress installation to live at blog.example.com, and any wordpress links to remain under blog.example.com/xyz, and not to redirect to example.com/wordpress.

I've tried so many configurations of virtual hosts, and I have managed to get blog.example.com to load the wordpress landing page, but any links take me to example.com/wordpress/ (I have tried updating the site and home urls in the database). Other configurations have caused me to fall into a redirect loop when loading the page, often looking like example.com/wordpresswordpresswordpress... - I'm guessing this is caused by a rewrite condition not terminating. I've also followed the guides on the bitnami wiki (though I suspect they don't make much sense anyway).

If you know how bitnami and wordpress play together, I would really appreciate a breakdown of what I need to do to get my wordpress module behaving itself. (You can assume there's nothing to backup). Thanks :)

Comment: What do you have for a config now?

Comment: Currently a fresh bitnami install with url and site changed to blog.mydomain.com in wp-config.php, and a vhost entry in bitnami-lamp/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-vhosts.conf which describes a servername and alias of blog.mydomain.com listening on *:80

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know about Bitnami, but to add WordPress to a sub directory, you need two things:

- a `index.php` in the root dir containing nothing than the following:

  ```
  <?php
  define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
  require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/YOUR-SUB-DIR/wp-blog-header.php' );
  ```
- In case you are using Apache, a `.htaccess` file containing the following:

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
  RewriteRule ^(/)?$ YOUR-SUB-DIR [L]
  RewriteRule . index.php [L]
  ```

Basically that's it. I can't tell you how to set it up on lighttp or nginx, but above is a sure shot on Apache with a single site install. If you are moving to a multisite/network install, you will have to set the relevant constant in your installs `wp-config.php` file, active the network through the admin UI and then follow the steps to update your `.htaccess` and `wp-config.php` file.

**EDIT** You want

```
blog.example.com
```

as your main domain - so add it as such in the WP admin UI settings. It seems you got a single site install, but *"any wordpress links to remain under blog.example.com/xyz"* is pretty cryptic in WordPress terms. Permalink structure is what you choose under "admin > Settings > Permalinks". If the site redirects you to `example.com?query=arg`, then you obviously have set `example.com` as your WordPress main domain.

Comment: Hi, If I want my blog to be accessible directly from blog.mydomain.com, such that visiting www.mydomain.com will take me to a different page (unrelated to wordpress). I attempted to resolve this by creating a vhost with servername blog.mydomain.com, but the page fails to load css and js resources because the vhost is suffixed with a wordpress/, and the requests are prefixed with wordpress/, my hackfix is a symlink within wordpress to its parent. This arrangement grosses me out and I was hoping for something better. Does that make sense or did I miss something from your answer?